# Paperclip and tempfile with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9

I'm trying to write a rails application where users can upload images, but Paperclip doesn't seem to be working for me.

I've gone through all the basic steps (added has_attached_file, the migration, making the form multipart) but I keep getting the same error whenever I try uploading an image:

> can't convert nil into Integer

Looking at the top of the stack

> ...rails3/lib/paperclip/processor.rb:46:in `sprintf'
>
> ...rails3/lib/paperclip/processor.rb:46:in `make_tmpname'
>
> .../ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:154:in `create'
>
> .../ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:134:in `initialize'

It seems the problem is in the tempfile.

My code:

_form.rb

```
<%= form_for @high_school, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

model/high_school.rb

```
...
validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 4, :allow_blank => true
has_attached_file :photo
has_many :students
...
```

Is this a known problem?  I basically followed the instructions from the github to the letter.

My environment: Rails3 and Ruby 1.9.2dev

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe paperclip supports ruby 1.9 yet.

Try dropping down to ruby 1.8.7 and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Oh well.

Comment: It indeed solves the problem but this is not a good solution. Did anyone tried the solution from kiew?

Answer (score 2):

you have to apply this patch http://github.com/dwalters/paperclip/commit/2a85add5f102db8773518f8ac30f7e2337bf7d13 to get paperclip working on 1.9.2 head for the can't convert nil into Integer error

Answer (score 2):

This has now been fixed in version 2.3.3 of paperclip. See this commit:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/1bcfc14388d0651c5fc70ab9ca3511144c698903

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.railsplugins.org/plugins/161-paperclip?criterion_id=5&version_id=123) somebody has similar problem to yours with Paperclip on ruby 1.9 (but there is no solution). So probably it is problem with ruby version.